# which traditions call god by derogatory terms to express love?

Tags: bhakti, love

siva is called "pittan" or madman as a term of endearment in tamil.  there is a famous double-meaning sentence to tie lemons and snakes together

"pittan mudiyerum" = ascends to the head of a madman - applies to a lemon because it is believed to cure insanity and is rubbed on the head of mad men and applies to a snake because its on the head of Siva.

Comment: You should check out Sri Ramakrishna Paramahamsa's style of worshipping Goddess Kali.

Comment: Bamakhyapa used to argue with Goddess Tara, and very badly...apparently.